# Wepsphere CORBA.BAD_OPERATION error

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-portal, websphere-6.1

I am getting the error below when I starts `websphere`. I really can not figure out what my problem is here. Any help and advicement would be appreciated. Thanks

Index  Count   Time of last Occurrence   Exception SourceId ProbeId
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
     1      1 24.10.2013 06:35:41:080 GMT org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.isLocal 3510
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
+    2      1 24.10.2013 06:35:42:284 GMT java.io.IOException com.ibm.ws.management.discovery.DiscoveryService.sendQuery 165

the log below is from dmgr_exception.log.

```
 ------Start of DE processing------ = [24.10.2013 11:24:44:982 GMT] , key = org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.isLocal 3510
Exception = org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION
Source = com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.isLocal
probeid = 3510
Stack Dump = org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION: The delegate has not been set!  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._get_delegate(ObjectImpl.java:80)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_local(ObjectImpl.java:381)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.isLocal(CNContextImpl.java:4901)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.<init>(CNContextImpl.java:365)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getCosRootContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:934)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:824)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:533)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:117)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:712)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.rebind(WsnInitCtx.java:247)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi.RMIConnectorController.start(RMIConnectorController.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.JMXConnectors.startRMIConnector(JMXConnectors.java:664)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.JMXConnectors.started(JMXConnectors.java:1653)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.workloadcontroller.WorkloadController.startedWorkloads(WorkloadController.java:649)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.workloadcontroller.WorkloadController.started(WorkloadController.java:595)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WLCImpl.start(WLCImpl.java:94)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:977)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:673)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:140)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:461)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:183)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:339)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:94)
```

Comment: Which version of Websphere are you using? There is a issue at IBM support (PMR PK54727 - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK54727) for this issue. I seems to have been fixed in recent versions.

Comment: the version is 6.1.0.0

Comment: This is tagged with websphere-mq and websphere-portal but are you actually using any of these or is it only WebSphere Application Server 6.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a log file with the incident report in (at least something close to) : `/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/default/logs/ffdc/<your server name>`.

It should contain more information (and a stacktrace).

EDIT :

Websphere 6.1 is qui old already, in fact IBM does [not support it anymore since 30 sept 2013](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21570083).

Since to problem seems to be [known and fixed](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK54727) in later release, I suggest you update to a more recent version, at least to a recent [fixpack of 6.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007951#61047). You can learn more about the process in [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24012718). [6.1.0.47 FixPack](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg24035508) is the last one. You simply need to download the PAK file and run the installer.

Comment: there is no any log file named my server name in ffdc directory. There are just daily created and named log files here.

Comment: Any sub-directory in ffdc? logs might have been stored elsewhere, you can verify that in Websphere application server configuration.

Comment: can you be a bit clear? it is the first time i am trying to use websphere. there are many server conf xml files in WAS. i do not know on which one i should focus

Comment: This might depends on the verison of Websphere you are using but, try to locate the Troubleshooting > Logs & Trace sections. There select your application server and you should find the localisation of the logs files for your application server.

Comment: but even if i run the startManager.bar and startNode.bat the web console of WAS is not working. I get connection refused.